# Allow MTP for specific devices on Windows and MAC

Tags: windows, macos, security, block, mtp

Is there any way to allow only specific devices to connect a computer through MTP protocol in Macos as well as Windows and block the rest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows and OS X are very different OS, there will be no uniform way to manage MTP devices on each of them.

For the Windows system I recommend you to investigate [filter drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/creating-a-new-filter-driver).

For the OS X there is no default way to use devices through MTP, so you should decide what exactly users interactions you want to filter out, and then decide to block some library using or maybe write a kernel extension that will be filter out access to some /dev/xxx node.